# Stacking/ensembling models with caret

Tags: r, caret, ensemble-learning

I often find myself training several different predictive models using `caret` in R.  I'll train them all on the same cross validation folds, using `caret::: createFolds`, then choose the best model based on cross-validated error.

However, the median prediction from several models often outperforms the best single model on an independent test set. I'm thinking of writing some functions for stacking/ensembling caret models that were trained with the same cross-validation folds, for example by taking median predictions from each model on each fold, or by training a "meta-model."

Of course, this might require an outer cross-validation loop.  Does anyone know of any existing packages/open source code for ensembling caret models (and possibly cross-validating those ensembles)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like Max Kuhn actually started working on a [package for ensembleling caret models](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/fusebox/), but hasn't had time to finish it yet.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I hope the project gets finished one day!

edit: I wrote my own package to do this: [caretEnsemble](https://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble)

Comment: Excellent work on this package!

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is called "model ensembling". A simple introductory tutorial with R code can be found here:
http://viksalgorithms.blogspot.jp/2012/01/intro-to-ensemble-learning-in-r.html

Comment: Not to be nit picky, but "ensembling" is right in the title of my post.  I'm very specifically looking for an R package for ensembling arbitrary models, which doesn't seem to exist.  Thanks for posting the code, though.  Maybe I'll write my own package!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for but this might help:
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper

It is how to use multiple models in caret.  The part you might be interested is section 5 on pg. 13.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a package that would take as an input a list of caret objects, and would then output the median, mean, or weighted mean average of their predictions.  More advanced functionality might include optimizing the weights through nested-cross validation.